# Как создать серверный скрипт и вызывать его в php

Tags: yii2, debian, cron

У меня есть задача: надо по команде дописать строку в crontab и создать несколько папок на сервере. Для этого, как я понял, надо написать серверный скрипт. Но мне еще надо передавать ему параметры и выполнять его по команде. Как это правильно сделать?

ОС - Debian 8, сайт написан на Yii2

Answer (score 0):

*сайт написан на Yii2*. ое..

вообще чтобы что-то дописывать в *crontab* (который давно заменили на systemd-timers) нужны определенные права.

и вы уверены что вам нужено это? Может быть вам проще пересмотреть идею и создать 1 скрипт для крона крутящийся на php который будет бегать по нужным вам элементам.  А сами элементы вы будете писать с помощью каких-либо других php с http.

А то что вы хотите сделать это надо делать мини приложение работающее в фоне, слушающего tcp(любой сокет)(открытый порт денег часто стоит) и принимающий данные. + это обезопасить... не.